# Why do I get UnauthorisedAccessException from ImportPfxDataAsync?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, certificate

I'm trying to import an X.509 certificate into my WinRT application. The certificate has been generated by exporting the certificate with its private key from the Certificates Manager in Windows in a PXCS #12 format.

I'm using the [`FileOpenPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207847) to choose the file. For ease of testing, I have hard-coded the password for the certificate into my method:

```
private async void LoadCertificateAsync()
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();

    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pfx");
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;

    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

    string certificateData = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer);

    string password = "47679005-c8b8-47b5-b54c-277b12854973";

    await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
            certificateData,
            password,
            ExportOption.NotExportable,
            KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
            InstallOptions.None,
            "Client Certificate");
}
```

The code runs up to the call to [`ImportPfxDataAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificateenrollmentmanager.importpfxdataasync), at which point I receive an `UnauthorisedAccessException` as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> WinRT information: _InstallResponse
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

The certificate I'm trying to upload is on my SkyDrive [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=36238DD7C12215C3!170&authkey=!ABFR4Pm-TmsF8UM).

I can't find any documentation to explain why I might get this error and no suggestion of what I need to do to resolve it, whether it's an error in the exported certificates, the configuration of the application or the environment.

Comment: not that it's much help, but the code seems to be fine as it's working on my machine

Comment: Then it is either machine-specific (oh noes) or there's something about the certificate I'm importing. I will load the certificate somewhere public.

Comment: I've uploaded a certificate for testing purposes and modified the password in the code. If you could try the code with the certificate, it may add clues.

Comment: downloaded the cert into my Desktop folder, used your password and no exception.  Changed password and got exception, as expected.  I am running as admin on machine (thinking that may be perhaps relevant given exception).  Do you have alternative environment to check it out on?

Comment: I can get a VM constructed - hopefully give me some clear results. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There was the same error in my code. 
The solution for me was to check capabilities **Shared User Certificates** and **Enterprise Authentication** in *Package.appxmanifest*

Comment: I was loading a certificate locally, and trying to put it into the app's cache. To make it work I needed only Shared User Certificates (didn't need the Enterprise).

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works also without Enterprise Authentication, seems like it was necessary for another purpose.